# What is the cost of pagers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Two brothers have broken arcade machines and they sell them each for the amount of machines there are. They use the money to buy cell phones priced at \$10 each and one pager which is less than \$10. If they divide the devices (cell phones and pager) between them so that they each have the same amount of devices. How much does the pager cost?

I tried solving for `P` where `P = cost of pager`

and I also tried substituting multiple amounts of `n` machines and, my buddy thinks we fell into the Pigeonhole Principle.

How can I proceed to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have $n$ broken machines, they sell the lot for $n^2$ dollars.  We have $n^2=10a+p$ where $p$ is the price of the pager, less than $10$, and $a$ is the number of cell phones.  They have $a+1$ devices, which they are able to divide evenly, so $a$ is odd.  If you look at the list of square numbers, you can quickly find the value of $p$.  You should prove that given $n^2=10a+p$ with $p \lt 10$ and $a$ odd, $p$ must have that value.  Write $n=10c+d$, square it, and see what $d$ can lead to $a$ being odd.